# Create a Utility Class that show an UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uialertview

I have this Alert:

> There is no internet connection available, please try again.`

and I have to many code blocks that can produce this message and I want to put the `UIAlertView` in one class that I would not create it everytime, is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

h file  for ActionGeneric class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ActionGeneric : NSObject {

}

+(void)showAlert;
@end
```

m file

```
    #import "ActionGeneric.h"

    @implementation ActionGeneric

     +(void)showAlert{
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"haveInternetConnection",@"") 
                                                      message:@"" 
                                                     delegate:nil 
                                            cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"kOk",@"") 
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
    }
    @end
```

Then you just import action generic and call it

```
[ActionGeneric showAllert];
```

You should look at [Learning Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594-CH1-SW11)

Answer (score 2):

Sure it is. You could make it a class method for your class, so that you don't require any instances of it. Then you could call something like:

```
[InternetAlert displayAlert];
```

or something similar.